# Can the Samsung Galaxy Image Filter SDK be used for non-Samsung Android devices?

Tags: android, filter, samsung-galaxy-camera

The SDK can be found [here](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#image-filter).

Can it be used by other devices?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about this API?

Comment: If you check out the page itself, it says "Image Filter SDK has the following restrictions: Devices with Android 4.1 Jelly Bean (API level 16) or higher support Image Filter." That would make me conclude that it can be used for non-samsung devices. But you'll want to test that maybe, just in case.